# Why Vue 2 remove every thing when using :is prop override component?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

Please see this minimum example, I have a simple component called `HelloWorld.vue`

### HelloWorld.vue

```html
<template>
  <div class="foo">bar</div>
</template>
```

When I using this component like this

### App.vue

```html
<template>
  <HelloWorld />
</template>

<script>
  import HelloWorld from "./HelloWorld.vue";

  export default {
    components: {
      HelloWorld,
    },
  };
</script>
```

This rendered HTML looks like this

### Rendered HTML

```html
<div class="foo">bar</div>
```

However, when I add `:is` prop, rendered HTML changed

### App.vue

```html
<template>
  <HelloWorld is="h2" />
</template>

<script>
  import HelloWorld from "./HelloWorld.vue";

  export default {
    components: {
      HelloWorld,
    },
  };
</script>
```

## Rendered HTML

```html
<h2></h2>
```

Why is this happening?

Is it possible to overwrite only the outer HTML tag just like the `class` and `style` prop?

Comment: https://vuejs.org/v2/api/#is

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`<HelloWorld is="h2" />` efficiently renders `h2` instead of `HelloWorld`.

In order for root element to be configurable, the component should provide this:

```
<template>
  <component :is="tag" class="foo">bar</div>
</template>
<script>
export default {
  props: {
    tag: {
      type: String,
      default: 'div'
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 2):

`is` should be used together with the `component` element:

`<component is="h2"></component>`

Comment: OK, thank you. So if I use `:is` with the component, everything will be wiped out, right?

Comment: Probably, but you can/should use slots in that case :)